# Existence of random variables whose difference of squares is normally distributed

Tags: normal-distribution

Are there independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that the distribution for $Z = X^2 - Y^2$, is $Z \sim N(0, 1)$?

Comment: There's no need to square $X$ and $Y:$ just stipulate that they have non-negative support.  // For some intuition, notice that sums of *iid* copies of $Z$ are also Normal and can be expressed as a difference of sums of *iid* copies of $X^2$ and sums of *iid* copies of $X^2$ (because evidently $X^2$ and $Y^2$ have the same distribution), thereby producing a sequence of solutions once you have any solution at all.  The CLT tells us what such a sequence will look like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that $X$ and $Y$ are required to be independent, since otherwise the question is not very interesting.

By [Cramer’s decomposition theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%27s_decomposition_theorem), if $X^2-Y^2$ were normal, then both $X^2$ and $-Y^2$ would be normal, contradicting the fact that $X^2$ is always at least zero and $-Y^2$ is always at most zero. So $X^2-Y^2$ can not have a normal distribution.

Comment: Interesting, do you happen know a modern-ish reference?

Comment: This theorem is the first of Benhamou, Guez, and Paris’s “Three Remarkable Properties of the Normal Distribution”, at https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.01768. They give a self-contained version of a complex-analytic argument by Feller, so the proof is modern (from five years ago!) but too long for summarizing in a comment.

Comment: Perfect Thank you!